# Can I use Windows Authentication with ASP.Net Identity?

Tags: windows, authentication, asp.net-identity

Am I mad?

I can create authentication providers using OWIN and ASP.Net Identity for Facebook, google, etc.  But I have a requirement to authenticate my users against Windows.  I'd rather not require the configuration of AD, or to tell IIS what Domain to authenticate against; I just want the IIS to authenticate as if the settings was Windows Authentication in the Web config.

But then I want to be able to get roles and user details.  I want Roles in SQL Server.  I also require the user first and last name, which are not directly available from windows auth).

In the past I have done this with a mixed authentication middleware, and grabbed the user details from the principle context when creating the user, store that in SQL, and in the authentication cookie. but this seems a bit of overkill here.

Has anyone succesfully used basic Windows Authentication but held roles and first/last name in sql?

thanks

Comment: perhaps this will nudge you in a right direction: http://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Windows authentication with ASP.NET and IIS.

[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/323176), should be a good start.

You can then store users and their AD groups in the application, and manage access based on that mapping.

Comment: That article talks about old MembershipProvider. This does not work in modern Asp.Net Identity.

Comment: Hi trailmax - thanks for the comment. Ok, I didn't realise it had to be integrated with Asp.Net Identity.

Comment: Actually, Asp.Net Identity is NOT a requirement.  The requirements are that I do NOT want to have a logon page.  Users are either authenticated against the server or shown an unauthorized page.  If a user does not exist in my SQL server database, the user will be created.  I am using a repository pattern to gain access to the data via EF.  In my database I will store additional roles which need to be validated by User.IsInRole or the Validate Attribute.  I also need to add the Users first and last name to the cookie so that it can be displayed on screen instead of their windows login id.

Comment: The solution also needs to authenticate across MVC and WebAPI.